# Allow user to define context menu items

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to allow users of this class to define the menu context items, as in different use cases we'll need to expose different context menu items.

Source XAML

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu
               Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={SomeConverter}}">
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

How I'd like to use it:

```
<x:MyCollectionControl>
    <MenuItems>
        <MenuItem Header="Do Something"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <MenuItem Header="Do Something Else"
                Visibility="{Binding SomeCondition}" />
    </MenuItems>
</x:MyCollectionControl>
```

What do I need to add to the control or view model to expose the context menu items so they can be defined where I'm using the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, I worked out a fix about 5 minutes after posting this.

Added the following to my control code.

```
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
  public ItemCollection MenuItems => MyCollectionDataGrid.ContextMenu?.Items;
```

And used this to reference the control.

```
<trade1:MyCollectionControl x:Name="SomeDataGrid">
    <trade1:MyCollectionControl.MenuItems>
        <MenuItem Header="Do Something"
                Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <MenuItem Header="Do Something Else"
                Visibility="{Binding SomeCondition}" />
    </trade1:MyCollectionControl.MenuItems>
</trade1:MyCollectionControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the ContextMenu's ItemsSource binded to a collection property in your ViewModel.

Assuming all your ViewModels inherit from a certain Interface(your own) they could implement a getter to this collection and if the have items or not(for disabling the ContextMenu).

For anything else you will have to be more specific.